# Symfony two way authentication

Tags: php, authentication, symfony-security, symfony-2.8

I'm developing a symfony 2.8 app with authentication on remote server. Authentication is passed via either a form or api keys (simple_preauth). On successfull authentication a session key is saved in cookies so that my simple_preauth authenticator (with stateless set to true) checks it on each request. That simple_preauth authenticator allows 2 things: to authenticate a user via secret api keys passed in get parameters and also check if current session is expired on remote server. Only authenticated users are allowed doing anything. So there is my security.yml file:

```
providers:
    webservice:
        id: app.webservice_user_provider

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER}

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        provider: webservice
        stateless: true
        simple_form:
            authenticator:  app.form_authenticator
            login_path:     /login
            check_path:     /login_check
            success_handler:    app.auth_success_handler
        simple_preauth:
            authenticator: app.sessionlogin_authenticator
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /login
            success_handler:  app.logout_handler
```

**Problems**:

1. The setting "stateless: true" in the security.yml file disables target_path redirection after login ([Exception Listener on github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/ExceptionListener.php#L193)). In fact "stateless: true" is needed just for simple_preauth and no needed for simple_form. Maybe there is a correct way to break the firewall into two firewalls still keeping the ability to authenticated both via form and api keys?
2. Maybe there is a more right way to organise access controll so that just authenticated users could access pages?

Comment: This is what happens when you have a powerful security component with absolutely crappy and incomplete documentation...